Ask a question about hypergeometric functions by $_2F_1\left(\frac38,\frac38;\frac54;-z\right)$
Recently I was plagued by a difficult problem about hypergeometric functions, I know that there are quadratic transformation
$$_2F_1\left(\frac38,\frac38;\frac54;-z\right)=
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+z}}{2}\right)^{-\frac14}\times\ _2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;\frac54;\frac{1-\sqrt{1+z}}{2}\right)$$
I'm trying to prove the following equation
$$\small\begin{aligned}&\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+z}}{2}\right)^{-\frac14}\times\ _2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;\frac54;\frac{1-\sqrt{1+z}}{2}\right)\\\\=&\
\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)^2}{4\,\pi^{3/2}}\ \ \Big[4z(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})\Big]^{-\frac14}\\\\ \times&\ \left[
K\left(\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}}\right)-K\left(\sqrt{\frac12-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}}\right)\right]\end{aligned}$$
where $K$ is The first kind of complete elliptic integral
$$
K(z)=\ _2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;z^2\right)=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-z^2\sin^2\theta}}
$$
It stumped me, I just know
$$K(x)=\frac{2}{1+y}\times K\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)\qquad\qquad x^2+y^2=1$$
But it doesn't work. If anyone can give an answer, I'll be overwhelmed ;-)

Solution
Thanks everyone, I resolved the issue a few days ago
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/13812985017[][1]
The original problem arises from a proof of the following Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$
\bbox[#CAF,30px,border:1px]{\small\begin{aligned} _3F_2\left(\frac34,\frac34,\frac34;\frac54,\frac32;-z\right)=&\ \frac{\Gamma(\frac14)^4}{8\pi^3}\times\frac1{\sqrt{z(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}\\\\ \times&\ \left[\mathbf{K}\left(\frac12+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}\right)-\mathbf{K}\left(\frac12-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}\right)\right]^2 \end{aligned}}
$$
Firstly, I used the Clausen identity
$$
\bbox[#FAA,20px,border:1px]{\,_3F_2\left(2a,2b,a+b;2a+2b,a+b+\frac12;z\right)=\ _2F_1\left(a,b;a+b+\frac12;z\right)^2}
$$
Then got
$$
\bbox[#FEA,20px,border:1px]{_3F_2\left(\frac34,\frac34,\frac34;\frac54,\frac32;-z\right)=\, _2F_1\left(\frac38,\frac38;\frac54;-z\right)^2}\tag1
$$
Then, based on the two important quadratic transformations of the hypergeometric function
$$
\begin{aligned} &\bbox[#ACF,20px,border:1px]{_2F_1\left(a,b;a+b+\frac12;-z\right)=\, _2F_1\left(2a,2b;a+b+\frac12;\frac{1-\sqrt{1+z}}{2}\right)}\\\\ &\bbox[#FEA,20px,border:1px]{_2F_1\left(a,b;2b;-z\right)= (1+z)^{-\frac{a}{2}}\times\, _2F_1\left(\frac a2,b-\frac a2;b+\frac12;\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)} \end{aligned}
$$
the following transformation formula was obtained
$$
\bbox[#CFA,20px,border:1px]{\begin{aligned} _2F_1\left(a,b;a+b+\frac12;-z\right)=&\ (\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{z})^{-2a}\\\\ \times&\ \, _2F_1\left(2a,a+b;2a+2b;2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})\right) \end{aligned}}
$$
Applying this formula to the hypergeometric function on the right side of $\small(1)$
$$
\small\bbox[#FAA,20px,border:1px]{_2F_1\left(\frac38,\frac38;\frac54;-z\right)= (\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{z})^{-\frac34}\times\, _2F_1\left(\frac34,\frac34;\frac32;2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})\right)}\tag2
$$
Based on the linear dependence of the solutions to the hypergeometric equation, combined with their analytic continuation properties, we know
$$
\small\bbox[#ACF,20px,border:1px]{\begin{aligned}  _2F_1&\left(a,b;\frac32;z\right)= \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{2\sqrt{z}\,\Gamma(-\frac12)\Gamma(a+b+\frac12)}\\\\\\ \times&\ \left[\, _2F_1\left(2a-1,2b-1;a+b-\frac12;\frac{1-\sqrt{z}}{2}\right)-\, _2F_1\left(2a-1,2b-1;a+b-\frac12;\frac{1+\sqrt{z}}{2}\right) \right]\end{aligned}}
$$
It mean
$$
\small\bbox[#FEA,20px,border:1px]{\begin{aligned}  _2F_1&\left(\frac34,\frac34;\frac32;2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})\right)= -\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)^2}{2\pi\sqrt{\pi}} \frac1{\sqrt{2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})}} \\\\\\ \times&\ \left[\, _2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;\frac{1-\sqrt{2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})}}{2}\right)-\, _2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;\frac{1+\sqrt{2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})}}{2}\right) \right]\end{aligned}}
$$
Combining this with the hypergeometric function representation of the first kind of complete elliptic integral
$$
\bbox[#FAC,10px,border:1px]{\mathbf{K}\left(k\right)=\,_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;k^2\right)}
$$
Therefore
$$
\small\bbox[#FAA,30px,border:1px]{\begin{aligned}  2F_1\left(\frac34,\frac34;\frac32;2\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{1+z}-\sqrt{z})\right)=&\  \frac{\Gamma(\frac14)^2}{2\pi\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}}} \\\\\\ \times&\ \left[ \mathbf{K}\left(\frac12+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{z})}}\right)- \mathbf{K}\left(\frac12-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{1+z}+\sqrt{z})}}\right)\right]\end{aligned}}
$$
Finialy, it has been elegantly proven that the original problem
$$
\bbox[#CAF,30px,border:1px]{\small\begin{aligned} _3F_2\left(\frac34,\frac34,\frac34;\frac54,\frac32;-z\right)=&\ \frac{\Gamma(\frac14)^4}{8\pi^3}\times\frac1{\sqrt{z(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}\\\\ \times&\ \left[\mathbf{K}\left(\frac12+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}\right)-\mathbf{K}\left(\frac12-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1+z})}}\right)\right]^2 \end{aligned}}
$$

A very preliminary comment (I have not done any work on this yet) but have you had any progress in proving this by reverting both the hypergeometric functions and the elliptic integrals back into their integral representations?

Yeah, but it's so hard... ...
